How do I keep a camera pointed at a stationary object while moving the camera on X or Y axis?
So, I need the camera to stay "looking" at a particular point while I shift it on X & Y axes. It would rotate on its Z axis to keep pointed at the target.There's no animation involved, I will be moving the camera manually.

Do you try to add to the camera a Track To constraint, selecting "-Z" as Track Axis and "Y" as Up ?

Actually, yes, that's it! Wasn't working before because the origin of the object it was constrained to was way out of its geometry! All I had to do was to set the origin correctly and it works like a charm.

Hello, Dan .. (I hope I haven't misread this) It seems you have a fix without  requiring an answer here, and your post can fairly be called a duplicate. If you disagree, please go ahead and edit for re-opening. Thanks.
